# What's in Assassin's Creed Unity "special edition"?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I've decided to buy Assassin's Creed Unity for PS4. I went to the store and the only one I could find was a "limited edition" one. I could not find a standard one anywhere. What is supposed to be special about this version, which apparently is more abundant than the standard version?

Comment: Does the box not say on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the 4 editions here at [videogamer.com](http://www.videogamer.com/ps4/assassins_creed_unity/news/assassins_creed_unity_special_editions_revealed.html)

The websites says:

> **Special Edition:**
>    - The AC Unity game
>    - 1 additional single player mission for an extra 30 minutes of gameplay

The additional mission states:

> **The Chemical Revolution:** Antoine Laurent de Lavoisier is considered to be the "Father of Modern Chemistry". As a result of his efforts, he was able to create the formula for a poison bomb. Unfortunately he was taken before he could give it to you. Help him escape his kidnappers and recover the formula of the precious bomb.